# Data transfer between Processor and FPGA through GPMC using EDMA

Tags: linux

We are working on a board containing AM3359 processor.

SDK we are using is ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-05.00.00.15.

Our customer wants to see the throughput of the data transfer between processor (AM3359) and FPGA connected through 8 GPMC lines using EDMA

All we want now is to implement GPMC_EDMA data transfer program as per the below flow.

[Processor and FPGA lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31qcS.png)

Processor booted ----> Run GPMC_EDMA Data transfer program ----> Complete data transfer ----> Calculate throughput.

Here is my code for transferring data to FPGA through 8 GPMC lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                      
#include <stdint.h>                                                          
#include <stdlib.h>                                                          
#include <termios.h>                                                         
#include <string.h>                                                          
#include <unistd.h>                                                          
#include <fcntl.h>                                                           
#include <errno.h>                                                           
#include <time.h>                                                            
#include <sys/mman.h>                                                        

#define FATAL do { fprintf(stderr, "Error at line %d, file %s (%d) [%s]\n", \
  __LINE__, __FILE__, errno, strerror(errno)); exit(1); } while(0)

int verbose = 0;                                                                                                      

#define BUF_SIZE 4096                                                                                                 

int main(){                                                                                                           
    int i,fd;char ch;                                                                                             
    int buf[BUF_SIZE];                                                                                            
    volatile uint8_t *map_base;                                                                                   
    int a=1;   

    for(i=0;i<BUF_SIZE;i++){                                             
            if(i%100==0){                                                
                    a++;                                                 
                    printf("i: %d,   a: %d\n",i,a);                      
            }                                                 
            buf[i]=a;                                                    
    }                                                                    
    //buf[BUF_SIZE]=43;                                                  

    if((fd=open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1) {                   
            printf("Error in opening gpmc\n");return 0;                  
    }                                                                    
    printf("Successfully opened\n");                          

    map_base =(uint8_t *) mmap((void*)0x01000000, 0x01000000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x01000000);
    if(map_base == (void *) -1) FATAL;                                                                            
    if (verbose) {                                                                                                
      printf("Memory mapped at address %p.\n", map_base);                                                         
      fflush(stdout);                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                             
    volatile uint32_t *p32 = (uint32_t *) &map_base[0x0800];                                                      
    //while(1/*(ch=getchar())!='\n'*/){                                                                           
            //*p32 = 0x1;                                                                                         
            for(i=0;i<BUF_SIZE;i++){                                                                              
                    *p32 = buf[i];                                                                                
            }                                                                                                     
            printf("Sent %d bytes\n",BUF_SIZE);                                                                   
    //}                                                                                                           
    printf("Closing FD\n");                                                                                       
    close(fd);                                                                                                    
}
```

Someone kindly help me to proceed further as we have a severe time restriction and also we are new to this one.

Regards
Vamsi

Comment: Please don't create "questions" that are just links to another site. If you have a question, write it here so that there's no need to go to some other site

Comment: SDK we are using is ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-05.00.00.15.

Our customer wants to see the throughput of the data transfer between processor (AM3359) and FPGA connected through 8 GPMC lines using EDMA

As of now we are able to send data to FPGA through these 8 GPMC lines.

Comment: SDK we are using is ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-05.00.00.15.

Our customer wants to see the throughput of the data transfer between processor (AM3359) and FPGA connected through 8 GPMC lines using EDMA

As of now, we are able to send data to FPGA through these 8 GPMC lines. We've developed a c program to send data to FPGA through GPMC. Now we are not clear about how to proceed further in this regard on how to associate this gpmc program with EDMA protocol in Linux-SDK to send data to FPGA.

Comment: If you need to add something to your question, use the [edit] link. Don't post things in the comments.